# Information to include in a many to many relational table

Tags: many-to-many, relational-database

I am trying to put together a database that holds the relation between computers and orders where a computer can exist on many orders and an order can show many computers.

I have the structure so that there is an extra relational table showing the computers_orders_relationship.

My table shows, for example, computer_id, order_id, location_id, comments, etc that are specific to the computer for the specific order.

I'm confused whether I should add specific information about the specific order for that specific computer in the computers_orders_relationship table... any pointers?

Comment: Yes **specific information about the specific order for that specific computer** should be in that junction table. It is an option, however, to add an auto-number field to the junction table and have this linked to another table that contains all these specific details.

I am a little suspicious, though, of the location_id being in there. Is it also specific to that order and that (specific) computer?

Comment: I would also name the table computers_orders. This makes it clear that it is a junction table, without the need for '_relationship' (IMO).

Comment: Thanks, I think that cleared things up. It gave me a good start for the next phase of the database design as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes **specific information about the specific order for that specific computer** should be in that junction table.

It is an option, however, to add an auto-number field to the junction table and have this linked to another table that contains all these specific details. This can be more efficient if there a lot of details, and easier to maintain.

Comment: This is where I keep getting confused in the relational world. I've understood junction tables to only contain the junction, and then my logic isn't developed enough to understand how the auto increment would connect the descriptions. I like where your suggestion is going, though. Could you maybe give a simple example?

Comment: I keep trying to imagine a unique name for each record that contains the computer serial and order number. Those should really be the only two columns (or whatever the relational name is) in the table. Then I could easily call the order by selecting the ID where the computer is x and/or order is y. Am I on track?

Comment: I would typically merge the field-names, ComputerOrderID, this makes its purpose very clear. There is an example [here](http://www.utteraccess.com/wiki/index.php/Junction_Tables_(Many-to-Many_Relationships)) of an M2M relationship with an additional auto-number field. If you search I'm sure you'll find a fuller example.